# Remove similar entry in dictionary

Tags: python

I have the dictionary:

```
hostServiceDict = {"http://192.168.1.1:80/thredds/catalog.xml": ['OPENDAP', 'WMS', 'HTTP', 'ISO'],
"http://192.168.1.2:80/thredds/catalog.xml": ['OPENDAP', 'WMS', 'HTTP', 'ISO', 'UDDC'],
"http://192.168.1.3:80/thredds/catalog.xml": ['OPENDAP', 'WMS', 'HTTP', 'ISO', 'HTTPServer'],
"http://192.168.1.4:8080/thredds/catalog.xml": ['OPENDAP', 'WMS', 'HTTP', 'ISO', 'NetcdfSubset'],
"http://192.168.1.5:8080/thredds/catalog.xml": ['OPENDAP', 'WMS', 'HTTP', 'ISO', 'WCS', 'NCSS'],
"http://192.168.1.5:80/thredds/catalog.xml": ['OPENDAP', 'WMS', 'HTTP', 'ISO', 'WCS', 'NCSS'],
"http://192.168.1.6:80/thredds/catalog.xml": ['OPENDAP', 'WMS', 'HTTP', 'ISO', 'DAP4'],
"http://192.168.1.7:80/thredds/catalog.xml": ['OPENDAP', 'WMS', 'HTTP', 'ISO', 'NCML', 'DAP4'],
"http://192.168.1.8:80/thredds/catalog.xml": ['OPENDAP', 'WMS', 'HTTP', 'ISO', 'NetcdfSubset'],
"http://192.168.1.9:80/thredds/catalog.xml": ['OPENDAP', 'WMS', 'HTTP', 'ISO', 'UDDC'],
"http://192.168.1.18:80/thredds/catalog.xml": ['OPENDAP', 'WMS', 'HTTP', 'ISO', 'NetcdfSubset'],
"http://192.168.1.18:8800/thredds/catalog.xml": ['OPENDAP', 'WMS', 'HTTP', 'ISO', 'NetcdfSubset']
}
```

Two entries have some ip address but the port part is different for `http://192.168.1.5 and http://192.168.1.18`. I need to remove the second duplicated one to make it like:

```
hostServiceDict = {"http://192.168.1.1:80/thredds/catalog.xml": ['OPENDAP', 'WMS', 'HTTP', 'ISO'],
"http://192.168.1.2:80/thredds/catalog.xml": ['OPENDAP', 'WMS', 'HTTP', 'ISO', 'UDDC'],
"http://192.168.1.3:80/thredds/catalog.xml": ['OPENDAP', 'WMS', 'HTTP', 'ISO', 'HTTPServer'],
"http://192.168.1.4:8080/thredds/catalog.xml": ['OPENDAP', 'WMS', 'HTTP', 'ISO', 'NetcdfSubset'],
"http://192.168.1.5:8080/thredds/catalog.xml": ['OPENDAP', 'WMS', 'HTTP', 'ISO', 'WCS', 'NCSS'],
"http://192.168.1.6:80/thredds/catalog.xml": ['OPENDAP', 'WMS', 'HTTP', 'ISO', 'DAP4'],
"http://192.168.1.7:80/thredds/catalog.xml": ['OPENDAP', 'WMS', 'HTTP', 'ISO', 'NCML', 'DAP4'],
"http://192.168.1.8:80/thredds/catalog.xml": ['OPENDAP', 'WMS', 'HTTP', 'ISO', 'NetcdfSubset'],
"http://192.168.1.9:80/thredds/catalog.xml": ['OPENDAP', 'WMS', 'HTTP', 'ISO', 'UDDC'],
"http://192.168.1.18:80/thredds/catalog.xml": ['OPENDAP', 'WMS', 'HTTP', 'ISO', 'NetcdfSubset'],
}
```

I have tried this but it still gives me the same result as origin:

```
result = {}
for urls, services in hostServiceDict.items():
    i = urls.strip('http://').strip('thredds/catalog.xml').split(':')
    ip = i[0]
    if ip not in result.items():
        if ip in urls:
            result[urls] = services

print(result)
```

Comment: in : ip is urls: you are checking the ip is inside urls, for example: "http://192.168.1.18:80/thredds/catalog.xml"
"http://192.168.1.18:8800/thredds/catalog.xml":  both of them contains 192.168.1.18..

Comment: your line `if ip not in result.items()` does not work since items returns you tuples of (key,value). So first you are only interested in the keys. Then you can check whether the key contains the ip. So you should do something like: `for url in result.keys(): if ip in url: ip_found = true` and finally `if not ip_found: result[urls] = services`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if ip not in result.items():` never finds the `ip`, because IPs are not in `results`.
You have to keep track of the IPs you've seen:

```
result = {}
seen_ips = set()
for url, services in hostServiceDict.items():
    ip = url.strip('http://').strip('thredds/catalog.xml').split(':')[0]
    if ip not in seen_ips:
        seen_ips.add(ip)
        result[url] = services

print(result)
```

---

To make the code even better, you could do real url parsing:

```
import re

def get_host(url):
    return re.match(r'https?://([^:/]+).*', url).groups(0)
```

Then it is easier to make a host -> (url, services) dictionary, instead of removing duplicates "manually":

```
data_by_hostname = {get_host(url): (url, services)
                    for url, services in hostServiceDict.items()}
```

This dict took care of removing the duplicate hostnames.

And then, if you want, you can again construct the url -> services dictioonary from the values:

```
result = dict(data_by_hostname.values())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep track of distinct ips by having a list and validating the new ip with already tracked ips this will require a small change in your logic as follows:

```
result = {}
distinct_ips = []
for urls, services in hostServiceDict.items():
    i = urls.strip('http://').strip('thredds/catalog.xml').split(':')
    ip = i[0]
    if ip not in distinct_ips:
        distinct_ips.append(ip)
        if ip in urls:
            result[urls] = services

print(result)
```